# Switch keyboard from terminal?

Tags: macos, keyboard, input-source

Is there a command line equivalent to pressing ctrl-space to toggle the keyboard layout? (I need this because I want to use Karabiner to tap shift to toggle.)

Answer (score 1):

Make an applescript:

`tell application "System Events"
    keystroke " " using control down
end tell`

PS. This is too slow, and allows more keys from the old keyboard to be entered before the switch is effectual.